# How to put the random values for a variable and how to refresh that random value every 30 seconds?

Tags: java, random, timer

How to put the random values for a variable and how to refresh that random value every 30 seconds?

i have got some idea from the site for getting random value as follows,

```html
Random r = new Random();
String i = r.next()%33;
switch (i) {
  case 0:
    myVariable = "a";
  case 1:
    myVariable = "b";
  case 2:
    myVariable = "c";
}
```

But i could not find exactly to refresh the value every 30 seconds

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with RMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String[] myVariable = {""};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt() % 33;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                myVariable[0] = "a";
            case 1:
                myVariable[0] = "b";
            case 2:
                myVariable[0] = "c";
        }
    }
}, 0L, 30000L);
```

Comment: including `default` in every switch is better

Comment: it's up to you, the point is generate random value and set to `myVariable `, so you could use it in outer code

Comment: for more than one variable at the same time what can i do?

Comment: i don't quite understand, can u describe concretely, eg. usage scene

Comment: i mean ,  in the above example, i suggested only one vaiable called myVariable , i am asking that, if we want to add more than that variable , what solution needed?

Comment: i still don’t understand what you mean. what’s “one variable called myVariable”? if u need different random value for each client, you can try to put the myVariable in to a ThreadLocal.